# Unity.AutoRegistration not auto-registering

Tags: c#, unity-container, auto-registration

I'm trying to use [Unity.AutoRegistration](http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/) to auto wire my interfaces to the implementations. My configuration looks like this:

```
public static class UnityConfigurator
{
    public static UnityContainer Configure()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.ConfigureAutoRegistration()     
                 .LoadAssemblyFrom(typeof(UnityConfigurator).Assembly.Location)
                 .LoadAssemblyFrom(typeof(ICountryFilterDataRepository).Assembly.Location)
                 .ExcludeSystemAssemblies()
                 .ExcludeAssemblies(a => a.GetName().FullName.Contains("Specs"))                     
                 .ApplyAutoRegistration();
        return container;
    }
}
```

But it's not working :( I get this error, which clearly implies the mapping hasn't been set:

> The current type,
>   Blah.IFoo, is
>   an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?

What's wrong with my config code? Thanks

Comment: What's the name of implementation that should be wired for IFoo ? Are you sure the assemblies for your interface and implementations are loaded in your autoconfiguration ?

Comment: @ThomasJaskula Same name, IFoo maps to Foo, and implementation and interfaces are in the same assembly.

Comment: @Charlie Not familiar with AutoRegistration but the home page seems to state you need to also make use of an Include; `.Include(If.Implements<IFoo>, Then.Register().WithName("Foo"))`

Answer (score 2):

Adding this line should fix the issue

```
.Include(If.ImplementsITypeName, Then.Register())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try an alternative to Unity.AutoRegistration.

The [TecX](http://tecx.codeplex.com) project on CodePlex has a port of the StructureMap configuration engine including its support for registration by convention. The configuration for Unity can be found in TecX.Unity.Configuration. There are UnitTests that show how it is used.

---

**UPDATE:**

With TecX auto registration of IFoo would look like this:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.Scan(
  x =>
  {
    x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
    x.With(new ImplementsIInterfaceNameConvention());
  });
```